# Using python function output to update individual postgresql rows

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm working on a project that requires a column in postgresql to be updated by the Mapbox geocoding api to convert an address into lon,lat coordinates. I created a FOR loop to read in the address from each row. I'd like to then save the unique lon,lat coordinates created into the "coordinates" column.

However, the code I've written updates the entire "coordinates" column with the first row's lon,lat coordinates, rather than iterating and updating each row's "coordinates" column individually.

Where did I go wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Main Code**

```
import psycopg2
import json
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import sys
from mapbox import Geocoder
from mapboxgeocode import getCoord
import numpy as np 

con = None

try:

    con = psycopg2.connect(database='database', user='username') 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS permits")
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE permits(issued_date DATE, address
    VARCHAR(200), workdesc VARCHAR(600),permit_type VARCHAR(100),   permit_sub_type
    VARCHAR(100), anc VARCHAR(4), applicant VARCHAR(100),owner_name       
    VARCHAR(200))""")
    cur.execute(""" COPY permits FROM '/path/to/csv/file'
    WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER """)
    cur.execute("""ALTER TABLE permits ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
    UPDATE permits set id = DEFAULT;""")
    cur.execute("""ALTER TABLE permits ADD COLUMN coordinates VARCHAR(80);
    UPDATE permits SET coordinates = 4;""")
    cur.execute("""ALTER TABLE permits ADD COLUMN city VARCHAR(80); 
    UPDATE permits SET city = 'Washington,DC'; ALTER TABLE permits ALTER    
    COLUMN city SET NOT NULL;""")

    cur.execute("UPDATE permits SET address = address || ' ' || city;")

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM permits;")

    for row in cur.fetchall():
        test = row[1]
        help = getCoord(test)
        cur.execute("UPDATE permits SET coordinates = %s;", (help,) )
        print(test)
        con.commit()



except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    print 'Error %s' % e    
    sys.exit(1)


finally:

    if con:
         cur.close()
         con.commit()
         con.close()
```

**Geocode Function**

```
from mapbox import Geocoder
import numpy as np

def getCoord(address):
    geocoder = Geocoder(access_token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    response = geocoder.forward(address)
    first = response.geojson()['features'][0]
    row = first['geometry']['coordinates']
    return row
```

Comment: FWIW, triple-quoting Python strings means you can split your SQL up onto multiple lines which makes it easier for humans to read.

Comment: Thanks, I just made some changes @WayneWerner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a WHERE condition in your UPDATE statement.  Without WHERE, SQL simply thinks you want to update all of the coordinates columns.  A proper WHERE condition will let it know specifically which cell in the column it needs to modify.

You'll probably want to use your primary key, as it's a unique identifier.  Perhaps a statement along the lines of:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE permits SET coordinates = %s WHERE id = %s;", (help, row[index of the id column]) )
```

I think the row index you need would be row[8], but you'll have to confirm that in your code.  I hope that gets it working.

Comment: It's better to use cursor as dictionary, that way you can access columns by their name rather then by indexes.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  I didn't know you could do that.  So, something like this:
`row[id]`?